# Django multiple signals with one receiver

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to add a `post_save` and a `post_delete` signal to a receiver. However, I am getting an error that says: `TypeError: change_followers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'created'`

```
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Following)
def change_followers(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.follower.following_count += 1
        instance.target.follower_count +=1
        instance.save()
    else:
        instance.follower.following_count -= 1
        instance.target.follower_count -=1
        instance.save()
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The [**`post_delete`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete) does *not* send a `created` parameter.

You can however easily fix this by adding a default value to the parameter:

```
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Following)
def change_followers(instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.follower.following_count += 1
        instance.target.follower_count +=1
        instance.save()
    else:
        instance.follower.following_count -= 1
        instance.target.follower_count -=1
        instance.save()
```

Note that the logic is however still **incorrect**: since if you update a model instance, you will trigger the `post_save`, but that does *not* mean that that instance is removed. Furthermore if you update a model instance, that can imply that the `target`/`follower` changes, and thus you should decrement that count.

Furthermore it is probably not a good idea to use signals to calculate followers counts anyway, since certaing Django ORM calls can *bypass* the signals. It might be better to annotate your objects with the number of `Following`s. If you use signals, you will need to periodically run a query that synchronizes the amount.

Comment: I dare to say that storing information that can be easily calculated is a code smell.

Comment: Hmm, but if my logic is just if user follows another user increment by 1, what needs to be synchronized if I'm not calculating anything except incrementing the model field by 1?

Comment: @user2896120: as said, you can *bypass* the signals. For example the `Following.objects.bulk_create(..)` will *not* trigger signals. Furthermore if you perform a `Following.objects.update(..)` that will again bypass it. If you *alter* a `Following` object, you need to decrement the *old* following, and increment the *new* one. Signals can be useful, but frequently these are an anti-pattern: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Comment: @PauloScardine: well it is in essence data-duplication, which is always to some extend a code smell, since synchronizing data tends to be (suprisingly) hard problem :).

Comment: I see what you are saying, but if my code does not have bulk_create or update, then aside from that signals would be useful?

Comment: @user2896120: if you have a `Following` object that has been saved, and you trigger it a second time here, then you will again decrement the followers count (since the second time `created` is not `True`). Furthermore if you alter the `.follower` of a `Following`, and save it, then you will decrement (which is wrong), and you will even not decrement the `.follower` that you left, but the new one.

Comment: So I should just manually increment/decrement whenever the following model changes?

Comment: I'm also very confused, if signals has all these downfalls, what is the point of it anymore?

Comment: @user2896120: well there are basically two options: you can `.annotate(..)` your `Follower` model with the number of followers, etc. each time. Or you should accept that the number is not always entirely correct, and for example add a regular task to update the number of followers by running a query that fixes the number of followers.

Comment: @user2896120: as the article mentions at the bottom, there are a limited number of good use cases, but not that much.

Comment: What if the number of followers field is in the User model? The Following model only contains the follower, the target, and thats it. Couldn't I just update it through the User model each time instead?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the post_delete signal signature does not include a "created" parameter - what would be the meaning of "created" in the post_deleted context?

One solution is:

```
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Following)
def change_followers(instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("created"):
        instance.follower.following_count += 1
        instance.target.follower_count +=1
        instance.save()
    else:
        instance.follower.following_count -= 1
        instance.target.follower_count -=1
        instance.save()
```